# range based for loop with std::list of shared_ptr

Tags: for-loop, c++14, shared-ptr, stdlist

I have two template declarations as follows:

```
template<typename T>
class A{
public:
T& getData();
//rest of public
private:
shared_ptr<A<T>>& X;
shared_ptr<A<T>>& Y;
shared_ptr<A<T>>& Z;
T& data;
};

 //template constructor definition
 template <typename T> A<T>::A(T& rData, 
                               shared_ptr<A<T>>& rX,
                               shared_ptr<A<T>>& rY, 
                               shared_ptr<A<T>>& rZ): X(rX), 
                                                      Y(rY),
                                                      Z(rZ),
                                                      data(rData){
     //rest of definition}

 //definition for getData()
 template <typename T> T& A<T>::getData(){return data;}


template<typename T1, typename T2>
class B{
public:
using typAContainter = class std::list<shared_ptr<A<T1>>>;
B(int, T2&);
//rest of public
private:
typeAContainer C;
//rest of private
};
```

Inside the constructor definition for B, I use two distinct (yet similar in logic) debug code segments (Note that I had to resort to debug code segment 1 since debug code segment 2 did not give the expected output, which is the issue I am facing as well):

```
template<typename T1, typename T2> B<T1, T2>::B(int I, T2& rData){

  auto iter = C.begin();
  auto count = 0;
  //a workaround to create three 
  //dummy shared_ptr instances to
  //type A<T>
  vector<shared_ptr<A<T1>>>dummys(3);
  for(; count < I ; ++count, ++iter)
     {
        *iter = make_shared<A<T1>>(rData[count],
                                   dummys[0],
                                   dummys[1],
                                   dummys[2]
                                  );
       //Debug code segment 1
       #ifdef DEBUG
      std::cout << (*iter).get()->getData() << std::endl;
      #endif
     }

   //Debug code segment 2
   //doesn't give any output
   for(auto Aref : C)
     {
      std::cout << Aref.get()->getData() << std::endl;
     }
}
```

Since the debug code segment 2 does not produce any compiler error, I assume that the syntax is correct. Can anyone point out the logical error due to which I don't get the expected output?

Comment: Try `for(auto& Aref : C)`.

Comment: @KerrekSB No that doesn't work either

Comment: Are you including the `make_shared` command? `Aref = make_shared ...`?

Comment: @KerrekSB No,  am using the same code segment as reproduced in the question.

Comment: `C` is empty.  `iter` is not dereferenceable, equal to `C.end()`. `*iter = ...` therefore exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Based on the fact that debug statement 1 works, wouldn't it be correct to assume that C should not be empty when I get to debug statement 2?

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined. You put data into some random place in memory, and read it back. You got lucky that the program didn't crash. How can `C` not be empty when you never add any elements to it? In any case, print `C.size()` and see for yourself.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I guess my understanding is flawed. I assumed that since I point iter to the beginning of C before entering the loop where I assign to *iter and increment the iter, I am in effect constructing C. From what you point out, which is right, that is not the case. What should be the right way of writing to C then?

Comment: You assumed incorrectly. I suggest you consult your favorite C++ textbook for an explanation of how to populate a container. See e.g. [`std::list::push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/push_back)

Comment: @user9196120: OK, so what I was suggesting was: `for (auto& Aref : C) { Aref = make_shared<A<T1>>(rData[count], ...); std::cout << Aref->getData() << std::endl; }` -- i.e. populate the container as you go along, and print the new value. As discussed above, this assumes that your container `C` already contains (possibly null) elements; if `C` is empty, the range will of course not contain any rounds.